# How can I add not list adapter items to a list view?

Tags: android, listview, layout, view, listadapter

I am making an android app where I will have a custom listarray adapter that adds list view items (no problem here).. however.... I want to be able to add not list-array items (it will be a custom linear layout that is a form) to the list view(i will be translating list items up so the form will be on top). is this possible?

my end result would be so:
 i want to get list items

I want to click a button

I will use layout inflater to get a view from another xml and then add it to my list view with out passing it through the list adapter.

any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is functionality that you should write into your adapter class.  Do not circumvent the adapter.  The list view is relying on the adapter to serve up views, and the adapter is performing recycling so that new views don't have to be inflated every time the user scrolls up and down.

Adapters have a couple methods that are designed to let you serve up different views for different list view rows: `getItemViewType(int position)` and `getViewTypeCount()`.  For every different type of row you want to inflate, have a different private method to do the inflation (or recycling, just like you normally would with the ViewHolder pattern).  In your `getView()` method, call the appropriate private helper to inflate the view, based on what type of list item it is -- your view can be just about anything.

Comment: So in that same swipe I can see how many of those "special list items exist" so i can get the count of the listview and the special list items?

Comment: The Adapter will be serving up these views from a data set - you can always consult that data set to find out what kind and how many items there are, as well as their relative positions.  The list view will only be in charge of displaying views, and it's not the source of truth for the data.  The list view may only display (and thus only "know about") the contents of the screen.

Comment: I am trying to do what you said by adding a private method to my custom adapter but I cant seem to get my methods to work where i can invoke a change in my adapter + add the layout i want to inflate. do you have a quick example(sorry new to java)

Comment: If you've made some change in the underlying data set that backs the adapter and would like to notify the list view that it needs an update, you can call notifyDataSetChanged().  Remember that the adapter doesn't force it's views into the list -- it only responds when the list explicitly asks for the 'next' view in the data set (such as when the user scrolls down and the list view needs to know what to display next).

Comment: I know that, I was wondering how i Can actually build the view in my getview method in the array adapter because in the adapter i have the xml to inflate.. so my question is how can i switch that xml for certain list rows?

Comment: if (thisRow = special) { //inflate some xml} else {inflate other xml}.  One of the getView parameters is the position of the item in the data set.  Consult the data set to see if that item is "special", and inflate different xml.  Remember to use the viewHolder pattern to recycle that layout if you've already inflated it once.